# Width of li with two floats different in IE, correct in FF

Tags: jquery, css, width, css-float

I've worked out most of the kinks with my "lava-lamp" effect that I'm trying to create.  Basically I want two curly braces (both are images) to wrap a list-item, then follow over to the next list-item.  I always build in FF, then make exceptions for IE.  I can't figure out what exception I need to make!

I'm using an absolutely positioned `li` that contains two `div`'s.  The first `div` is floated left, the second is floated right.  The width of the `li` is set to the width of the `li` it supposed to be wrapping.  Thus creating the effect of the braces on the left and right sides of the text.  It works beautifully in Firefox, but IE has two issues:

1. The bottoms of the images are cut off.  Sometimes they reappear when the animation ends, sometimes they don't.  I assume this has to do with height, but no matter what I set the height to, it fails!
2. The width is completely wrong.

Here's a live example of it: http://jsbin.com/odome/2

The left position in IE is always 5-7px more than in FF, but that's a small difference.  I'm more concerned with the width and the bottoms of the images being trimmed.

Thanks, as always, for the help!

Comment: Just a side-question: do you need to float the `li` s, couldn't you `display: inline;` them?

Comment: I've always used floats, but I couldn't say why.  The first tutorial I read used floats probably.  Doesn't affect the outcome here though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) your ul#selection-test is not properly "cleared"

2) it doesn't seem like you want your li to wrap, so add a white-space: nowrap

3) Opinion: I don't know how I feel about using li#blob as the lava in your lamp. If it was me I would do something like this

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul id="selection-test">
    <li>Menu Item One</li>
    <li>Menu Item Two</li>
    <li>Menu Item Three</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="lava">
    <div id="lava-left"></div>
    <div id="lava-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [CSS reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/) to make lists behave cross-browser.

Comment: That doesn't fix either issue I'm experiencing, unfortunately.  On the live site I do make use of a CSS reset.  Here's the example with the CSS reset: http://jsbin.com/odome/3

Comment: I would just use a DIV for the floating bracket item, not a list-item. I think that has something to do with it.

Comment: good call!  Switching to a `div` seems to have helped a lot, but now the centering of it is off.  I'll have to play with the calculations I guess.  You can see it now at http://jsbin.com/odome/6